# Protect server URL in mobile app

Tags: url, mobile

I know this can sound absolutely stupid, but I could not find any way to solve this problem.

Say I've a mobile app: from this app, after purchasing an item, since the item is downloadable from a server, I make the user download a file to his device. Problem is it looks like it is very easy even for not so smart people, to get the URL of the file, so, without purchasing anything, the not-so-smart-guy can eventually download the same file for free (using a common browser).

Apart from the language I use (it is not important here, it can be JavaScript, Java, Objective-C, whatever), how can I prevent this issue WITHOUT developing an authentication system?

Comment: IIRC, this wouldn't even pass the UX guidelines as you purchase outside of an IAP from within the app.

Comment: Cole, I'm not sure, but if you want to make a PDF downloadable from the Apple (library/newspapers) store, the file must be on your server, not Apples'. But I could be wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generate a token for successful purchase, store it in the server side session or database. Add the token as a query string parameter for the file download request.  Implement an filter for the file download request to validate the token.

To make sure that the URL is not share able - find some unique attribute of the device that can't be spoofed easily, hash(url,token,unique property) and add it to the url.

Comment: Ok. Would it be a good idea to have a sort of temporary token?

Comment: Yes, it is better to use temporary tokens.  The only issue is that after successful purchase if the download fails for some reason the user should be able to download later, the expiry time should take this into consideration.